# Android use smileys keyboard

Tags: android, chat, emoji

I am working on an Android chatting application. I need to show, a smileys or emoji's keyboard, like that of 'Whats App'. Is there any such default keyboard for Android? If yes, how do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on what the user currently has installed. I use SwiftKey on my phone so I have the ability to use the Emoji's. If you are willing to put in the effort to create your own Emoji keyboard then toobsco42 has a great basic explanation of the process as well as a link to  a repo that you can use.

Comment: what do the other chatting applications do? Do they use their own custom keyboard?

Comment: Chatting applications generally use the default keyboard that the user has provided. If you take a look at the Facebook messenger app however you will notice that they have their own custom Emoji (called stickers in this case) keyboard that you can use. The issue really comes down to how defined you want this to be. Do you want the depend on the user having an Emoji keyboard or do you want to have them use your own custom one on top of the keyboard that they currently have.

Answer (score 0):

i would say start by getting the font with all the unicode charset for your application and render them in an layout invoked on the button in your input field. 
One of the website to create custom fonts : icomoon.io